# How do I upgrade the kernel in Ubuntu Server 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-10.04

I'm running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS.  When I login I see the message:

```
39 packages can be updated.
18 updates are security updates.
```

The usual formula of

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

gives me a message I've not seen on this box:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
```

If I give the go ahead to the apt-get upgrade the rest of the packages are upgraded as I expect.

How do I update the kernel files?

EDIT: I missed this earlier question and answer that basically solved my problem:

[Can someone clarify Ubuntu (Debian) dist-upgrade for me?](https://serverfault.com/questions/46748/can-someone-clarify-ubuntu-debian-dist-upgrade-for-me/46749#46749)

Comment: Adding on to the question, where does `aptitude safe-upgrade` and `aptitude full-upgrade` fit in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually, in this case you would want to use ***apt-get dist-upgrade***

If you do **not** wish to run *dist-upgrade* by fear of breaking something by an accident removal, you can also tell *apt-get* to upgrade only the packages that were kept back, like this:

In your case:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
```

Just specify the packages from the list that *apt-get* gave you (i.e. "*The following packages have been kept back*").

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is the solution to my problem.  After running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I also need to run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then reboot the server.  This seemed to work for me, but if anyone has more experience please feel free to edit this answer, comment on it or supply a better answer.

Comment: See this [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/46748/can-someone-clarify-ubuntu-debian-dist-upgrade-for-me/46749#46749) about the differences between `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you, Zoredache, that cleared up my confusion as to what dist-upgrade was actually doing.  I didn't want to accidentally upgrade my LTS server box to the next version of Ubuntu.  Now I know it won't.